# Cypress and find the element programatically, but its there and the UI can select it

Tags: cypress

I am having issues get'ing a css selector, its on the dom, and it can even be selected via the UI.

But cypress fails to get it.

There is not async stuff going on, just the page that was loaded.

As you can see in the image thelement is there, any ideas how to get round this?

[image]

Comment: Some suggestions. 1. Add a wait before the GET just to double check, we want to make sure its truly visible. 2. Are there any overlays covering the element? 3. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say that the problem is with loading the page, maybe you should pass `timeout` paramater to the `cy.get()`, to make sure that Cypress waits long enough.

```
cy.get('nli-block-container .block-content', {timeout: 20000})
```

This should wait for 20 seconds for the element. If that doesn't work, please let me know, because it means that the problem lies elsewhere